# Interpretation of coefficient sign change and order of terms

Tags: r, logistic, binomial-distribution, intercept

I have a logistic regression with data that are kind of like this:

```
y <- rep(c("A", "A", "B"), each = 30)
x <- c(     rep(1, 12), rep(2, 18), rep(3, 16), rep(4, 12), rep(5, 2),
            rep(1, 3), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 8), rep(4, 10), rep(5, 4)  )

da <- data.frame(y = y, x = x)
table(da)
   x
y    1  2  3  4  5
  A 12 18 16 12  2
  B  3  5  8 10  4
```

I'd like to show that there are more A's than B's in `y` (instead of a Bernoulli with `p` = 0.5), even after controlling for `x`, so I fitted two logistic regression models and used an ANOVA to compare them.

```
mlogis.x              <- glm(y ~ x,     family = binomial, da)
mlogis.x.no_intercept <- glm(y ~ x + 0, family = binomial, da)

summary(mlogis.x.no_intercept)
summary(mlogis.x)

anova(mlogis.x.no_intercept, mlogis.x, test = "Chisq")
```

I have a few questions:

- Does what I did make sense overall?
- Is it okay to not have an intercept in the more basic model and then add it to the full(er) model?
- The coefficient for `x` changes sign between the two models, how should I interpret this?

Comment: What does it mean to show that "there are more A's than B's in y... even after controlling for x"? What does controlling for x have to do w/ anything? Either you have more A's or you don't. Why not just run a binomial test?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense... I might have been too focused on the interaction between x & y and wasn't thinking about it the right way.

Comment: So if I simply want to test whether there is an interaction, then I should run an ANOVA between an intercept-only model and an intercept plus x model?

Comment: How could there be an interaction? You have only 1 explanatory / predictor variable.